# Clustering Microservice Components

Tags: cluster-computing, microservices, failover

We have a set of Microservices collaborating with each other in the eco system. We used to have occasional problems where one or more of these Microservices would go down accidentally. Thankfully, we have some monitoring built around which would realize this and take corrective action.

Now, we would like to have redundancy built around each of those Microservices. I'm thinking more like a master / slave approach where a slave is always on stand by and when the master goes off, the slave picks it up.

Should we consider using any framework that we could use as service registry, where we register each of those Microservices and allow them to be controlled? Any other suggestions on how to achieve the kind of master / slave architecture with the Microservices that would enable us to have failover redundancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this for a couple of minutes and this is what I currently think is the best method, based on experience.

There are a couple of problems you will face with availability. First is always having at least one endpoint up. This is easy enough to do by installing on multiple servers. In the enterprise space, you would use a name for the endpoint and then have it resolve to multiple servers (virtual or hardware). You would also load balance it.

The second is registry. This is a very easy problem with API management software. The really good software in this space is not cheap, so this is not a weekend hobbyist type of software. But there are open source API Management solutions out there. As I work in the Enterprise space, I am very familiar with options like Apigee, CA, Mashery, etc. so I cannot recommend an open source option and feel good about myself.

You could build your own registry, if you desire. Just be careful how you design it, as a "registry of all interface points" leads to a service that becomes more tightly coupled.

Comment: What we want is just a failover instance that becomes active when the master goes down. It is more or less the same concept with Apache Kafka brokers!

Comment: Kafka solves this by having all of the nodes registered in a central location and having a lot of software surrounding it. But, I am smiling at the out of the box thinking, as most people look at Kafka as a message bus only and not as a blueprint for solving problems in other realms. But, yes, having a central "guaranteed up" service that registers endpoints is an option. Good luck on your solution.